# how to assign variable in json in restrequest c#

Tags: c#, json, variables, restsharp, rest-client

Here is my code.Everything works fine when I hard code message attribute in the json. I want to assign variable in 'message' attribute of the json.

```
var client = new RestClient("172.16.255.254:2016/settings");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\r\n\r\n\"_id\": 
\"98e8d3cd47fad6ce8e3f7b8d42cb4d9b\",\r\n\r\n\"_type\": 
\"SetRealtimeMessage\" ,\r\n\r\n\"message\": \"c3BlZWQgZXhjZWVkZWQh\", 
\r\n\"width\":240,\r\n\"fontBackground\":0,\r\n\"fontColor\": 
0xFFFFBF00,\r\n//\"fontColor\": 0XFFBF00,\r\n\"fontSize\": 
24,\r\n\r\n\"lineSpace\": 0,\r\n\r\n\"left\": 0, 
\r\n\r\n\"windowBackground\": 0, \r\n\r\n\"verticalPos\": 0, 
\r\n\r\n\"horizontalPos\": 0, \r\n\r\n\r\n\"showType\": 0, \r\n\"speed\": 20, 
\r\n\r\n\"moveCount\": 1,\r\n\r\n\r\n\"residenceTime\": -1\r\n\r\n}",  
ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

Comment: Creating a `JSON` in this manner is not a good and true way. try creating an object and then by using `Newton.Json` or ... try to Serialize your JSON Object.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid writing out a long JSON string manually, you can use the ubiquitous Newtonsoft.Json NuGet package to create a JSON string from an object.

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var message = "Hello, World!";

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new 
        {
            id = 123,
            message = message
        });

        Console.WriteLine(json);

        // {"id":123,"message":"Hello, World!"}
    }       
}
```

DEMO: https://dotnetfiddle.net/FPFrng

You can pass any object in, I'm just creating an anonymous object here for a simple demo.

Answer (score 2):

Use [JSON.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm) and serialize to json your object and send it.

```
var myVariable = ...

string message = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myVariable);
request.AddParameter("application/json", message);
```

Answer (score 2):

Short and ugly answer :

You can concate your JSON string along with your variable, such as

```
var MyValue = "bar";
var json = "{\"foo\":\"" + MyValue + "\"}"; // {"foo":"bar"}
```

---

Long and better (IMHO) way

Do not directly write JSON strings ! Do you notice how unreadable it is ? You can instead create anonymous objects and serialize them, using, in example, [json.net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeObject.htm) :

```
var MyValue = "bar";
var MyObject = new
{
    foo = MyValue
};
// using Newtonsoft.Json; // <--- taken from the nugget package newtonsoft.json
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyObject, Formatting.Indented);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

This outputs :

```
{
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string.Format()

```
request.AddParameter("application/json", string.Format("{\r\n\r\n\"_id\": 
\"98e8d3cd47fad6ce8e3f7b8d42cb4d9b\",\r\n\r\n\"_type\": 
\"SetRealtimeMessage\" ,\r\n\r\n\"message\": \"{0}\", 
\r\n\"width\":240,\r\n\"fontBackground\":0,\r\n\"fontColor\": 
0xFFFFBF00,\r\n//\"fontColor\": 0XFFBF00,\r\n\"fontSize\": 
24,\r\n\r\n\"lineSpace\": 0,\r\n\r\n\"left\": 0, 
\r\n\r\n\"windowBackground\": 0, \r\n\r\n\"verticalPos\": 0, 
\r\n\r\n\"horizontalPos\": 0, \r\n\r\n\r\n\"showType\": 0, \r\n\"speed\": 20, 
\r\n\r\n\"moveCount\": 1,\r\n\r\n\r\n\"residenceTime\": -1\r\n\r\n}",messageVar)
```

Comment: So you need to make that message property as the parameter, in `string.Format();` . But I recommend you to create a JSON Object property as mentioned by Kurt

Comment: Thanks. But for this I am getting exception as  Format string contains invalid placeholder

Comment: Oh sorry that may be because of the `{{` to be used while we have to print `{` `string.Format(" {{ \r\n\r\n\"_id\": ...... ` like this

Comment: This is not the right way to create a json like this